# ¿Cómo pasar variables(en tablas) entre paginas ? error de $_SESSION

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla(la cargo con una query en mysql)  con datos(nombre, apellido,  ventas totales del empleado) y un un botón "Ver Detalle" que me sirve para generar una query en la que muestro solo las ventas del empleado que esta en la fila en la que apretamos el boton.

Osea: pagina1> click en boton "Ver detalle" en fila 1 > El usuario es dirigido a pagina2 > Se genera una tabla filtrada donde el WHERE es el apellido del vendedor(variable idVendedor) de la fila 1, por lo tanto obtenemos solo las ventas de ese empleado seleccionado.

Mi problema es que usando $_SESSION para pasar la variable entre las paginas me sale este error "Notice: Undefined variable: idVendedor "

Aca les dejo mi codigo a ver si me pueden decir que estoy haciendo mal o darme alguna otra opcion para resolver el paso de variables

Pagina 1 (cuando hacemos click en el boton)

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['idVendedor'] = $row["apellido_vendedor"];
```

Pagina 2

```
session_start();
$idVendedor = $_SESSION[$idVendedor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Para la página dos, en lugar de `$_SESSION[$idVendedor];` (pues acá la palabra $idVendedor dentro a la variable de sesión está mal. Debe ser así: `$_SESSION['idVendedor'];`

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder (: ya hice el cambio que me sugeriste y ahora el error es: Undefined Index idVendedor. Realmente no entiendo que estoy hacienod mal

Comment: Comprueba que antes de comenzar el archivo php debe de haber session_start(); para después consumir la variable de sesión. Antes de cualquier variable de sesión debe haber un session_start();